# Linq group by multiple columns and getting extra values from table before group by clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm wondering if it's even possible here is some code sample:

I've a table named `Sample`:

```
| Id| Name| Address| ExtraColumn| ExtraColumn2|
```

Here is `class`:

```
public class Sample{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Address{get;set;}
   public float ExtraColumn{get;set;}
   public float ExtraColumn2{get;set;}
}
```

What I have now:

```
Model.Sample.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.Address}).Select(x => new {x.Key, Count = x.Count()});
```

But I need besides Key, values of `ExtraColumn` and `ExtraColumn2` for each 
`Sample` `entity` in single `database request`.

So the question is: 
**Is it even possible?**

**If so how to get it done?**

Comment: You want `ExtraColumn`, `ExtraColumn2 ` based on some condition i.e. either the first record, in ascending order etc.? Cz for each group you will get an `IEnumerable<Sample>`.

Comment: for each group `IEnumerable<Sample>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, this is what you want:-

```
Model.Sample.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.Address})
            .Select(x => 
                    new 
                     {
                        Name = x.Key.Name, 
                        Address = x.Key.Address,
                        Count = x.Count(),
                        obj = x.ToList()
                     });
```

Here, `obj` will contain the `List<Sample>` in each group.